# SQL Rows into Columns

Tags: sql, oracle

Please help me in converting my rows into columns and not duplicating them. I've been searching and applying for ways to do this but I cannot satisfy my requirement.

```
create table PROGRAMMER
(
PERSON varchar(15),
LANGUAGE varchar(20),
LEVELS varchar(15)
);

insert into PROGRAMMER (PERSON, LANGUAGE, LEVELS) values ('CARL', 'JAVA', 'SENIOR');
insert into PROGRAMMER (PERSON, LANGUAGE, LEVELS) values ('CARL', 'PHP', 'MID');
insert into PROGRAMMER (PERSON, LANGUAGE, LEVELS) values ('CARL', 'VB.NET', 'JUNIOR');
insert into PROGRAMMER (PERSON, LANGUAGE, LEVELS) values ('GARY', 'C#', 'MID');
insert into PROGRAMMER (PERSON, LANGUAGE, LEVELS) values ('GARY', 'VB.NET', 'MID');
insert into PROGRAMMER (PERSON, LANGUAGE, LEVELS) values ('RALPH', 'PHP', 'SENIOR');
insert into PROGRAMMER (PERSON, LANGUAGE, LEVELS) values ('RALPH', 'RUBY', 'JUNIOR');
insert into PROGRAMMER (PERSON, LANGUAGE, LEVELS) values ('RALPH', 'JAVASCRIPT', 'SENIOR');
```

I want to represent the table like this using "LEVELS" as the column **with some rows having the same person** as many times as they have the same levels in different languages.  The other columns will be empty if there is no entry.

```
|  PERSON  |  SENIOR  |    MID    |  JUNIOR  |
----------------------------------------------
|  CARL    |   JAVA   |    PHP    |   VB.NET |
|  GARY    |          |    C#     |          |
|  GARY    |          |   VB.NET  |          |
|  RALPH   |   PHP    |           |  RUBY    |
|  RALPH   |JAVASCRIPT|           |          |
```

Thank you.

Comment: Rows and columns are not interchangeable in SQL. You can rearrange rows via `ORDER BY` and you don't know their count in advance. You can only specify the column order when writing the query, and their count is known at the query-writing time. You should probably rethink your design entirely.

Comment: You create a column as platform and insert as level? Both are wrong. You cannot have a column named LEVEL.

Comment: from  this i guess its on _pivot_ ?

Comment: Edited the create table, sorry about that, thank you for editing this time, it was my first post and still didn't know how to properly present a table and a question. I'll be better next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot achieve this with transpose. rather try using `natural full outer join`

```
WITH T
    AS (SELECT
             P.*,
             ROW_NUMBER ( )
                 OVER (PARTITION BY PERSON, LEVELS ORDER BY LANGUAGE)
                 R
        FROM
             PROGRAMMER P)
SELECT
      PERSON,
      SENIOR,
      MID,
      JUNIOR
FROM
      (SELECT
            PERSON,
            R,
            LANGUAGE SENIOR
       FROM
            T
       WHERE
            LEVELS = 'SENIOR')
      NATURAL FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT
                                PERSON,
                                R,
                                LANGUAGE MID
                          FROM
                                T
                          WHERE
                                LEVELS = 'MID')
      NATURAL FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT
                                PERSON,
                                R,
                                LANGUAGE JUNIOR
                          FROM
                                T
                          WHERE
                                LEVELS = 'JUNIOR');
```

You get

```
PERSON          SENIOR               MID                  JUNIOR              
--------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
CARL            JAVA                 PHP                  VB.NET              
GARY                                 C#                                       
GARY                                 VB.NET                                   
RALPH           JAVASCRIPT                                RUBY                
RALPH           PHP                                                           

5 rows selected.
```

Comment: This is great! Yes this is exactly what I wanted to accomplish, I didn't know about Natural Joins at all since I just started learning SQL. Will this also work with SQL Server? I'll just try it instead as well.

Comment: There's nothing special about the `NATURAL` there, that's just for elegance.  For all join types except FULL OUTER JOIN,  I'd recommend using `A [INNER, LEFT OUTER, RIGHT OUTER] JOIN B ON (A.COL1 = B.COL1)`, with subsequent reference to COL1 qualified as A.COL1 for `LEFT OUTER JOIN` or B.COL1 for `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`.  NATURAL fits FULL OUTER JOIN well because without it, you'd have to refer to joining column COL1 as `COALESCE(A.COL1, B.COL1, C.COL1, ...) AS ACTUAL_COL1`.  I have no idea if SQL Server supports FOJ - if not, you'd have to do `(A LEFT OUTER JOIN B) UNION (B NOT IN A)`

Comment: Also - if you were using Oracle, change VARCHAR to VARCHAR2.  Google can explain why :-)

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot create a column called "LEVEL" in oracle since its a reserved keyword.
2. You create table and insert statements contradict
3. Each person can be associated to more than one language with same level of proficiency. So it is not possible to transpose based on levels.
4. Rather you can try to transpose based on languages.
5. If you have a definitive list of languages then you can use MAX and DECODE
6. PIVOT is not possible to use since it needs an aggregate function on string.!!
7. If you dont have a definitive list then you can use Oracle connect by

**Try this if you have definitive list of languages**

```
SELECT
      X.PERSON,
      MAX ( DECODE ( X.LANGUAGE, 'JAVA', X.LEVELS ) ) "JAVA",
      MAX ( DECODE ( X.LANGUAGE, 'PHP', X.LEVELS ) ) "PHP",
      MAX ( DECODE ( X.LANGUAGE, 'VB.NET', X.LEVELS ) ) "VB.NET",
            MAX ( DECODE ( X.LANGUAGE, 'C#', X.LEVELS ) ) "C#",
      MAX ( DECODE ( X.LANGUAGE, 'RUBY', X.LEVELS ) ) "RUBY",
      MAX ( DECODE ( X.LANGUAGE, 'JAVASCRIPT', X.LEVELS ) ) "JAVASCRIPT"
FROM
      (SELECT
            O.PERSON,
            O.LEVELS,
             O.LANGUAGE 
       FROM
            PROGRAMMER O) X
GROUP BY
      X.PERSON;


PERSON          JAVA            PHP             VB.NET          C#             RUBY            JAVASCRIPT     
--------------- --------------- --------------- --------------- -------------- --------------- ---------------
CARL            SENIOR          MID             JUNIOR                         
GARY                                            MID             MID            
RALPH                           SENIOR                                         JUNIOR          SENIOR         

3 rows selected.
```

Comment: I see that in this table, that would be the better way to represent the query. But for my requirement, those were the problems that I was asked to try to find a way to solve. The levels are definite to be those three only 'senior', 'mid', 'junior'. I guess the puzzle I have to solve is to how I can represent this where the person can be  in two rows depending if he has 2 languages in the same proficiency.

Answer (score 0):

it is good challenge in designing subqueries, try this query on your table `PROGRAMMER` as you said:

```
select t1.person,t1.language as SENIOR,t2.language as MID,t3.language as JUNIOR  
from
(select person,language from PROGRAMMER where levels = 'SENIOR' union all
select distinct person,null as language from PROGRAMMER where person not in(select distinct person from PROGRAMMER where levels = 'SENIOR'))t1,
(select person,language from PROGRAMMER where levels = 'MID' union all
select distinct person,null as language from PROGRAMMER where person not in(select distinct person from PROGRAMMER where levels = 'MID'))t2,
(select person,language from PROGRAMMER where levels = 'JUNIOR' union all
select distinct person,null as language from PROGRAMMER where person not in(select distinct person from PROGRAMMER where levels = 'JUNIOR'))t3
where 
t1.person = t2.person and t1.person = t3.person;
```

Comment: Hamidreza, yes it was a good but hard challenge for me, your answer in my sample table duplicates "RUBY" for "RALPH" so it did not meet the requirement. Still, thank you, maybe there is a way to modify your query that will show this result. I like looking at different ways to accomplish something.