# Oracle - transform rows to column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table with attributes id_customer, product, id_department.

Product values - mobile, navigation, notebook

```
    id_customer    product       id_department 
    1              mobile        5
    1              navigation    5
    1              mobile        6
    2              notebook      5
    3              notebook      6
```

I want to transform it to get:

```
    id_customer          id_department   mobile   navigation    notebook
    1                    5               true     true          (null)
    1                    6               true     (null)        (null)
    2                    5               (null)   (null)        true
    3                    6               (null)   (null)        true
```

Is it possible to do this using Oracle SQL?

Comment: transpose/pivot link here https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-convert-rows-to-columns-and-back-again-with-sql-aka-pivot-and-unpivot

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20188595/335858

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `pivot` operator (requires Oracle 11.1 or later):

```
with
  inputs ( id_customer, product, id_department ) as ( 
    select 1, 'mobile'    , 5 from dual union all
    select 1, 'navigation', 5 from dual union all
    select 1, 'mobile'    , 6 from dual union all
    select 2, 'notebook'  , 5 from dual union all
    select 3, 'notebook'  , 6 from dual
  )
-- End of simulated data (not part of the solution).
-- SQL query begins below this line. Use your actual table and column names.
select id_customer, id_department, mobile, navigation, notebook
from   inputs
pivot (max('true') for product in ('mobile' as mobile, 'navigation' as navigation,
                                   'notebook' as notebook))
order by id_customer, id_department
;

ID_CUSTOMER ID_DEPARTMENT MOBILE     NAVIGATION NOTEBOOK
----------- ------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
          1             5 true       true     
          1             6 true          
          2             5                       true
          3             6                       true
```

The only "trick" here is the quantity to be pivoted. It must always be an aggregate function - I used `max()`. Since all you want is a `'true'` marker, I am pivoting the `max` of a constant string, the string `'true'`.